# How to implement Signer Attachment in Docusign?

Tags: c#, docusignapi, electronic-signature

The requirement which I have regarding docusign is I need to implement Signer Attachment and that same scenario is mentioned at [https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/wiki/Code-Walkthrough-_-Signer-Attachments]

But I am not sure how do I achieve with code in C#. As not sure how do I attach it to Envelope?

I want to send someone a contract letter to sign and also request them attach few docs and when all of that is completed , those docs should be sent to my email.

Anyone knows if I can achieve it with docusign?

Comment: "But I am not sure how do I achieve with code in C#". You misunderstood the point of this site. We don't help with these kinds of questions, only tiny, bug-related ones, never do we write code for someone like this.

Comment: I am aware of that but I am not getting a way to add signerattachment to envelope which I have created.

Comment: I was able to achieve it , the idea was to add SignerAttachmentTabs to signer tabs and then add SignerAttachment to It.

Comment: You can submit an answer to your own question and then mark it correct, just so future people can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous entry is not bad... I got it working eventually. But this code below is solid, in production, and works great! It also uses anchor strings.

```
        EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        env.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document set";

        Document doc4 = new Document
    {
        DocumentBase64 = doc4PdfBytes,
        Name = "Voided Check Attachment", // can be different from actual file name
        FileExtension = "pdf",
        DocumentId = "4"
    };
        env.Documents = new List<Document> { doc4 };
        SignerAttachment signAttachDoc = new SignerAttachment
    {
        TabLabel = "Attach your voided check",
        DocumentId = "1",
        TabId = "1",
        PageNumber = "1",
        AnchorString = "/at1/",
        AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        AnchorXOffset = "0",
        AnchorYOffset = "0",
        AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false",
    };          
        Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
    {
        SignerAttachmentTabs = new List<SignerAttachment> { signAttachDoc }
    };
    signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;
       Recipients recipients1 = new Recipients
    {
        Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 }
    };
            env.Recipients = recipients1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we can do it while using C# SDK

create a signer object

```
Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.Name = recipientName;
        signer.Email = recipientEmail;
        signer.RecipientId = "1";
```

then create attachment tabs

```
signer.Tabs.SignerAttachmentTabs = new List<SignerAttachment>();
```

after which we need an attachment to add to it

```
SignerAttachment signDoc = new SignerAttachment();
        signDoc.TabLabel = "Attach your Other Doc";
        signDoc.DocumentId = "1";
        signDoc.TabId = "1";
        signDoc.PageNumber = "1";
```

And finally we add it to the tabs

```
signer.Tabs.SignerAttachmentTabs.Add(signDoc);
```